# Are questions about the business of AVP on topic here?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Since the sight is labeled Audio-Video production, one could make an argument that questions relating to the business side of fields like Audio Engineering and the more technical components of the music industry would be on topic here.

For example, would these be acceptable questions for AVP:

What do I need to do to my recordings to make them less likely to be pirated?

What is the expected cost of starting my own studio?

Comment: Both of those strike me as absolutely related to audio and video production, but you're right, they don't seem to be explicitly included per the faq.